# HTML5 Mobile Web App

Tags: javascript, android, html, css

I've just created the required HTML5 Mobile web pages(including the CSS3 and javascript pages). I've got the apk file from build.phonegap.com as well.
But I want it to be dynamic i.e I should be able to add content from my laptop.
I've searched a lot but I'm unable to get the right info on doing this. 
I just want to be adding simple text paragraphs from my local server(laptop) to the app on the go. What do I do ?

Comment: Exactly what you want to do?

Comment: I want to setup a local database on my laptop so that I can add whatever data I need to the app whenever I want. The app is more like a notification app. So if there are any new notifications, I should be able to push that data to the app. For that, please tell me the steps I should follow.

Answer (score 1):

Sound like you need to set up some type of json / sql web service.

Comment: AJAX would make this easy, specifically look into JSONP as standard JSON AJAX won't run as this will be considered cross-domain.

Comment: You also want to make sure to add an access origin whitelist to your app so you can access external content (this would get around the Xdomain issue)

Answer (score 0):

Use your machine's ip to do this.

Suppose your laptop ip is 192.168.1.1

Then from your application just use

```
http://192.168.1.1/your_appliction/webpage

replace  http://localhost/  to http://10.0.2.2/
```

EDIT:

Treat your laptop as remote server and access the files in it as you normally do in website building.

Comment: How do I do that once I get the apk of my app from PhonegapBuild Adobe ?

Answer (score 0):

From another post I think might help...

1- if you are building the whole site from scratch: You can create your site by any CMS like dotNetNuke or joomla which will allow you to login and edit what you want

2- if you are building just this page from scratch : You can build your page with online-editing in mind, in this case I recommend to build two pages one for for viewing content and the other for online-editing you can use any HTML-Editor control like [FCKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/demo)

3- if you are dealing with already built page : it will be easier to build administration page which you can upload the new version of the content page to it, and the administration page take care of replacing the content page

Or maybe even the knockout js plugin could be something to look into http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/LkqTU/

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed instructions. I'm dealing with the already built page. Can you gimme some more details as to how to create the administration page and how to make it replace the other pages ? I'd be really glad if you get into details of it!